# jenkins deploy war/ear to a container - why the .war file is renamed before it is deployed on the remoteserver

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm new to jenkins and have a problem. I created a maven project (maven integration plugin 2.12.1) in jenkins (ver. 1.638). I got the source-code via git (maven web application).

Everything works fine, but at the end the .war which is moved/deployed via deploy plugin to the remote server has a wrong name.

*I dont know why the .war file is renamed before it is deployed on the remoteserver.*

It is called services.war instead of services_admin.war.

Screenshot jenkins:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc5wK.png

pom.xml:

```
    <groupId>services_admin</groupId>[enter image description here][1]
    <artifactId>services_admin</artifactId>
    <name>services_admin</name>
    <description>services_admin</description>


<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                    <additionalProjectFacets>
                        <jst.java>6.0</jst.java>
                        <jst.web>2.5</jst.web>
                    </additionalProjectFacets>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.builder</buildcommand>
                        <buildcommand>org.eclipse.wst.validation.validationbuilder</buildcommand>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.nature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.eclipse.wst.common.modulecore.ModuleCoreNature</projectnature>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>services_admin</finalName>
    </build>
```

Build log:

```
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Building services_admin 2
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Deleting D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 120 resources
    [INFO] Copying 307 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Compiling 307 source files to D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\classes
    [WARNING] D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\src\main\java\de\...\services\java\util\Cryptographer.java:[34,40] BASE64Encoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

    [WARNING] D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\src\main\java\de\...\services\java\util\Cryptographer.java:[59,39] BASE64Decoder is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release

    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] Copying 3 resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Compiling 48 source files to D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\test-classes
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Tests are skipped.
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ services_admin ---
    [INFO] Packaging webapp
    [INFO] Assembling webapp [services_admin] in [D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin]
    [INFO] Processing war project
    [INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\src\main\webapp]
    [INFO] Webapp assembled in [2328 msecs]
    [INFO] Building war: D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin.war
    [INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 19.360 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-01-31T16:00:01+01:00
    [INFO] Final Memory: 46M/447M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
    [JENKINS] Archiving D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\pom.xml to services_admin/services_admin/2/services_admin-2.pom
    [JENKINS] Archiving D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin.war to services_admin/services_admin/2/services_admin-2.war
    channel stopped
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
    Deploying D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote
      Redeploying [D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin.war]
      Undeploying [D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin.war]
      Deploying [D:\Programme_x64\Jenkins\jobs\Mavenproject  - services Admin (Test)\workspace\target\services_admin.war]
    Finished: SUCCESS


remoteserver log:
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] log
INFORMATION: Manager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] log
INFORMATION: Manager: deploy: Deploying web application '/services'
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/manager] log
INFORMATION: Manager: Uploading WAR file to D:\Programme_x64\tomcat\...\webapps\services.war
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMATION: Deploying web application archive D:\Programme_x64\tomcat\...\webapps\services.war
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:15 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester begin
WARNUNG: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:24 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMATION: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/services] log
INFORMATION: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/services] log
INFORMATION: Set web app root system property: 'OsWebApp.root' = [D:\Programme_x64\tomcat\...\temp\6-services\]
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:25 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/services] log
INFORMATION: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:31 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMATION: Mojarra 2.1.13 ( 20120907-1514) für Kontext '/services' wird initialisiert.
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:32 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMATION: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy-Annotationen vorhanden.  Verwaltete Bean-Methoden, die mit diesen Annotationen markiert sind, lassen die entsprechenden Annotationen verarbeiten.
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:33 AM com.sun.faces.config.configprovider.BaseWebConfigResourceProvider getResources
WARNUNG: JSF1067: Ressource /WEB_INF/wickedcharts.taglib.xml, die von der Konfigurationsoption javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES angegeben wird, kann nicht gefunden werden.  Die Ressource wird ignoriert.
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:33 AM org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFORMATION: Running on PrimeFaces 5.3
Feb 01, 2017 9:50:33 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMATION: Deployment of web application archive D:\Programme_x64\tomcat\...\webapps\services.war has finished in 17,323 ms
```

Comment: Do you want the name services.jar instead services_admin.jar?

Comment: i want the name services_admin.war, but its end up with the name services.war on the remote server. On the server where jenkins is, in the path jenkins/jobs/myjob/ the war file exists with the right name service_admin.war.

Comment: Please put the maven build log as well.

Comment: Well in log it says services_admin.war. Anything in the server side log?

Comment: Added remoteserver log, it says that services.war is deployed... I dont understand where and why the file is renamed.

Comment: Can you rename it to servicesAdmin.war and try for once?

Comment: Has no effect on the file that is deployed on the remoteserver. Still services.war :(. Do you have an idea where the renaming of the the .war file happens?

Answer (score 0):

i dont use the "deploy plugin - deploy war/ear to a container" for this project. Instead of that im using now "Send files to a windows share -  CIFS Publishers".

The problem with the "deploy plugin - deploy war/ear to a container" i could solve :(.

Anyway thx for ur help :).

Best regards